# I can't install Doctrine Migrations via Composer

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I've searched everywhere to fix my problem but i think my problem is a new one and there is not solution.

I've added doctrine/migrations to my composer file, and when i type

```
composer update
```

this problem shows up:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing doctrine/migrations (dev-master a4f14d3)
    Failed to download doctrine/migrations from source: Could not delete /var/www/vendor/doctrine/migrations/.git/objects/pack/tmp_idx_1vS7c6:
    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing doctrine/migrations (dev-master a4f14d3)
[RuntimeException]
  Could not delete     /var/www/vendor/doctrine/migrations/.git/objects/pack/tmp_idx_1vS7c6:
```

My composer file:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability" : "dev",
"prefer-stable" : true,
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

After chmoding the /var/www/vendor i get this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing doctrine/migrations (dev-master a4f14d3)
    Cloning a4f14d3a3d397104e557ec65d1a4e43bb86e4ddf
    Failed to download doctrine/migrations from source: Could not delete /var/www/vendor/doctrine/migrations/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_V57bD0:
    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing doctrine/migrations (dev-master a4f14d3)
[RuntimeException]
  Could not delete /var/www/vendor/doctrine/migrations/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_V57bD0:
```

Comment: Looks like some access rights issue. Have you tried deleting `/var/www/vendor/doctrine/migrations` manually before running command?

Comment: Yes I did, after every attempt :(

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/vendor

Comment: @johnSmith Welp this did something i have another error :P I will update the main post in a moment